# Accuracy of Google AdWords Keyword Tool, compared to Google Trends

Tags: keywords, google-keyword-tool

Does anyone have any insight into how accurate Google Keyword Tool is? The reason why I ask is because I have found a keywords phrase using Google Keyword Tool that has 83,100,000 local monthly searches yet when I enter the same phrase into Google Trends the phrase isn't even recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I trust Google Keyword Tool more then I trust Google Trends, but neither are accurate. I would check to make sure you used "exact match" in the Keyword Tool, broad or phrase match will return inflated numbers.